# How to do local development with Facebook app?

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

There are many similar questions on SO but Facebook constantly changes settings and protocols, so answers provided several years ago no longer work or can't be applied.

I attempt to add Facebook Login to my app using JS SDK. When I try it from `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`, popup tells me that I must add this address domain to "Application domains" in app settings. However, this can't be done for localhost. Here's what I tried so far:

- Adding `127.0.0.1` or `localhost` to app domains, which gives an error message: "App domains must match the domain of the Secure Canvas URL, Mobile Site URL, Unity Binary URL, Site URL or Secure Page Tab URL. Please correct these domains: localhost".
- Creating test app and changing Site URL to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`, then adding `127.0.0.1` to app domains. This seemingly works, but after accessing settings page again settings remain unchanged and login doesn't work either.

What does seem to work is setting Site URL on main app, but this is undesirable - I want it to work with my production site URL and test apps are supposed to be used for development.

Comment: Don’t use IP addresses, but a proper domain name - `myapp.local` or something like that. And using non-standard ports also can cause trouble - I strongly recommend to stick to the HTTP default ports 80/443. (I can’t understand why so many people chose such weird development setupsin the first place. You get the most predictable results, when you test under conditions that match the production environment as closely as possible - and there you are most likely using 80/443, so why set up the local dev environment any different? Bad choice.)

Comment: Tried using `myapp.local` in test app settings, but it doesn't work - settings remain unchanged after refreshing the page.

Comment: Seems like the dashboard is broken for test apps - after clicking the "Save Changes" button, you can see in browser console that the request gets answered with a 500 error by Facebook. There’s already a bug report for this, and they say they’ll push a fix shortly. https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1867549180180403/

Comment: Indeed, what a coincidence. Thanks for your help.